# Mask in Chrome combining position absolute, overflow hidden, z-index and border-radius

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, image-masking

I am trying to achieve an effect, where I will have div with background image with content inside. This content should be flex-positioned div with the same image but blurred (while keeping its relative position to parent).

In search for salvation, I have discovered that certain combination of CSS rules make this exact effect, but only in Chrome.

```
.container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative; /* it is required */
  display: flex; /* it is required */
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/4848_46406748211_5572c760e0_320_240_nofilter.jpg);
}

.mask {
  z-index: 1; /* it is required */
  overflow: hidden; /* it is required */
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 1px; /* it is required */
}

.element {
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/4848_46406748211_5572c760e0_320_240_nofilter.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39um580g/16/

Chrome / Chrome Mobile:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

This is ridiculous. Is there a way I can make this solution cross-browser?

### Answer to Moorthy G:

Let's suppose my block is placed on the right side. Current behavior of Chrome version is as I desire:
[image]

Adding any kind of transform will make `.mask` relative, so it will destroy desired effect:
[image]

Comment: I would say chrome is wrong here. The element is positionned relatively to an upper element thus overflow shouldn't apply to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);` clips your mask.

```
.mask {
  z-index: 1; /* it is required */
  overflow: hidden; /* it is required */
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 1px; /* it is required */      
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0); /* Fix for Firefox*/
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Transform makes `.mask` relative, so blurred background is positioned incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, make sense. I'll update the answer. If I found any solution.

Comment: `clip-path` works, but it's not cross-browser solution.

Comment: It does not work in IE/Edge. I suppose I should just disable this effect in Microsoft browsers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak is this working fine with border-radius? I avoided the clip-path because I thought it will break the radius

Comment: @TemaniAfif In Chrome, Opera and Safari there is border-radius, in Firefox border-radius is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the mask element `position:absolute` so that the overflow will work as expected then you consider adjusting the `background-position` while adjust the position of the element to rectify the image position.

I used CSS variable to make it easy to adjust:

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  --img:url(https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/4848_46406748211_5572c760e0_320_240_nofilter.jpg);
  background:var(--img);
}

.mask {
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top:var(--t,0);
  left:var(--l,0);
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.mask::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background:var(--img) calc(-1*var(--l)) calc(-1*var(--t)); 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--t:20px;--l:80px">
  <div class="mask">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="--t:90px;--l:0px">
  <div class="mask">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--t:50px;--l:50px;--img:url(https://picsum.photos/320/240?image=1069)">
  <div class="mask">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is problematic if I want to use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak ok will try to find another way, but I saw you already accepted the clip-path solution. I guess that one is fine for you?

Comment: @TermaniAfif I accepted clip-path but it is not a perfect solution (its just okay for now). If you find anything else worth trying, (if I am correct) I should be able to change accepted answer.

I think this problem is worth giving a though.